# How to put a mapboxgl map in three.js without requiring two canvases?

Tags: video, three.js, mapbox-gl-js

I have put together a simple example of putting a mapboxgl map onto a surface in three.js.  This gives a better response than raster-based maps.  We wanted to do this to allow the maps to be on a surface in a mobile device view that always is 'down' when you point the phone downwards (this example here doesn't do that).

However, there is still a fair amount of memory being shuffled around - and would be more logical if the map was being drawn directly into the same webgl context as three.js - so the question is around improvements to the code along those lines.

The example below also shows a similar technique to put a video onto a surface in threes, but unfortunately doesn't work well on mobile devices - so likewise, any ideas along those lines also appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Texture from Canvas (Three.js)</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=0.3, maximum-scale=0.3">
</head>
<body>

<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.20.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.20.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

<script src="js/threejs/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/threejs/Detector.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery code to display an information button and box when clicked. -->
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- ------------------------------------------------------------ -->
<div id="three" style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px"></div>
<div id="map" style="position: fixed; left:0px; top:0px; width:512px; height:512px;"></div>
<video id="video" style="position: fixed; left:0px; top:512px;" src="/videos/Big_Buck_Bunny_small.ogv" controls="false"></video>
<script>
/*
    Three.js "tutorials by example"
    Original Author: Lee Stemkoski
    Modified by: Dr. Roy Davies to show mapboxgl
    Date: July 2013 (three.js v59dev)
*/
// MAIN
// standard global variables
var container, scene, camera, renderer;
var mapcanvas;
var mapmaterial;
var videocanvas;
var videomaterial;

// custom global variables
init();
animate();
// FUNCTIONS        
function init() 
{

    // SCENE
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    // CAMERA
    var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20000;
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
    scene.add(camera);
    camera.position.set(0,150,400);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);  
    // RENDERER
    if ( Detector.webgl )
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );
    else
        renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer(); 
    renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    container = document.getElementById( 'three' );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // LIGHT
    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(0,250,0);
    scene.add(light);

    // SKYBOX/FOG
    var skyBoxGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 10000, 10000, 10000 );
    var skyBoxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x9999ff, side: THREE.BackSide } );
    var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh( skyBoxGeometry, skyBoxMaterial );
    // scene.add(skyBox);
    scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0x9999ff, 0.00025 );

    ////////////
    // CUSTOM //
    ////////////

    DoMapTexture();

    DoVideoTexture();

}
function animate() 
{
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();       
    update();
}
function update()
{
}
function render() 
{
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

function DoMapTexture()
{
    // Using Mapbox GL
    mapboxgl.accessToken = '<YOUR MAPBOX ACCESS TOKEN>';
    map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/bright-v9',
        zoom: 1,
        center: [180,0],
        pitch: 0
    });

    // When it has finished loading, set up the sources and layers
    map.on("load", function ()
    {     
        // Find the newly created WebGL map canvas
        mapcanvas = document.getElementsByClassName('mapboxgl-canvas')[0];

        // A loader for the image
        var maploader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

        // load a resource
        maploader.load(
            // Convert the webgl 'image' to a 'url'
            mapcanvas.toDataURL(),

            // Load the map image
            function ( texture ) {
                // Place the material on a mesh
                mapmaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: texture, side:THREE.DoubleSide} );
                mapmaterial.transparent = true;
                var mapmesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry(500, 500), mapmaterial );
                mapmesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
                scene.add( mapmesh );
            }
        );
    });

    // Whenever it renders, redraw the texture
    map.on('render', function(e) {

        if (mapcanvas)
        {
            var maploader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

            // Reload the material
            maploader.load(
                mapcanvas.toDataURL(),

                function ( texture ) {
                    mapmaterial.map = texture;
                    mapmaterial.map.needsUpdate = true;
                }
            );
        }
    });
}

function DoVideoTexture()
{
    // Create a temporary 2D canvas as an intermediary for the texture
    var videocanvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    var ctx = videocanvas.getContext('2d');
    var video = document.getElementById('video');

    // set canvas size = video size when known
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
      videocanvas.width = video.videoWidth;
      videocanvas.height = video.videoHeight;
    });

    video.addEventListener('play', function() {
      var $this = this; //cache
      (function loop() {
        if (!$this.paused && !$this.ended) {
          ctx.drawImage($this, 0, 0);
            if (videocanvas)
            {
                var videoloader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

                // Reload the material
                videoloader.load(
                    videocanvas.toDataURL(),

                    function ( texture ) {
                        videomaterial.map = texture;
                        videomaterial.map.needsUpdate = true;
                    }
                );
            }
          setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 30); // drawing at 30fps
        }
      })();
    }, 0);

    // A loader for the image
    var videoloader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    // load a resource
    videoloader.load(
        // Convert the webgl 'image' to a 'url'
        videocanvas.toDataURL(),

        // Load the map image
        function ( texture ) {
            // Place the material on a mesh
            videomaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: texture, side:THREE.DoubleSide} );
            videomaterial.transparent = false;
            var videomesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry(200, 100), videomaterial );
            videomesh.position.set(100,100,0);
            scene.add( videomesh );
        }
    );
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am probably misunderstanding, but I would think using webGL maps, where javascript must do much heavy lifting, when you're also using three.js for further work on another aspect of the application is a bigger issue than using two canvases. Why not use the raster tiles available from mapbox on the restful tile endpoints on three.js plane geometry face materials?

Comment: We did do that originally, but the performance was not great (with Leaflet in between).  That said, it could be the way we did it rather than the technique per se.  Logically, however, since both mapboxgl and threejs are both using webgl, it should be easy enough to tie the two together without having to rasterise it into a texture on the way.

The problem there is telling mapboxgl to draw into a different surface than it currently does.

Comment: Were you using THREE.CSS3DObject to display a leaflet map as an iframe? What I am suggesting is to simply show the map tile imagery directly in the plane material - no map library whatsoever. If you've tried that, and it was not performant, something else is wrong.